# How do I implement Mongo DB query to find key in all objects inside an array?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars

After looking into several books, the mongo db reference and other stackoverflow questions, I can't seem to get this query right.

I have the following data structure:

Posts collection:

```
{
    "content" : "...",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "author" : "joe",
            "score" : 3,
            "comment" : "nice post"
        }, 
        {
            "author" : "bob",
            "score" : 5,
            "comment" : "nice"
        }]
}
```

What I'm trying to get is all of the *author* names inside each of the objects of the array **inside a Handlebars helper**, not in the console. So I would have something like:

```
...
 commentsAuthors: function() {
  return Collection.find({...});
 }
```

UPDATE:
I decided to reduce my array to only an Array of strings which I later queried like this:

New Array:

```
{
    "content" : "...",
    "comments" : ["value1", "value2", "..."]
}
```

MeteorJS Handlebars helper:

```
Template.courseEdit.helpers({
 comments: function(){
  var cursor = Courses.find({"_id": "8mBATtGyyWsGr2PwW"}, {"comments": 1, "_id": 0}).fetch();

 return cursor.map(function(doc, index, cursor){
   var comment = doc.comments;
   console.log(comment);
   return comment;
  });
 }
});
```

At this point, I'm able to render the Whole array in my view with this `{{#each}}...{{/each}}`:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
   {{#each comments}}
     <li class="pl-14"><i class="icon-checkmark"></i> {{this}}</li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```

However I'm getting the whole array in one single list item.

How can I create a separate list item for each of my Array strings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Should be as easy as (replace `posts` with your collection name):

```
db.posts.distinct("comments.author")
```

Or if you need it per post:

```
db.posts.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$comments" }, 
  { $group: { "_id": "$_id", authors: { "$addToSet": "$comments.author"} } } 
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I'm trying to specifically get all of the values of the keys of the objects inside the comments array. Any ideas how? NOTE: Within a Handlebars helper, not in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can get only certain fields by limiting fields

```
 db.collection.find({"content" : "..."},{"comments.author":1})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however I'm trying to specifically get all of the values of the keys of the objects inside the `comments` array. Any ideas how? NOTE: Within a Handlebars helper, not in the console.